# like html jsp <form> category and subcategory format not supports

Tags: html, css, jsp

As like `HTML` we can select Category and subcategory like:--

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

that represent like:

[image]

But I have to use in jsp form..How I can do that??

```
<form:select>
 <form:optgroup label="Swedish Cars">  </form:optgroup>
</form:select>
```

In jsp it is saying that 
  is an unknown tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `form:` in the tags in your jsp file? Just try removing them:

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: In jsp I need to do with <form:select>...is it possible??

Comment: I don't think you need to, try it without `form:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below:

```
   <form:select multiple="single" path="pathname" id="modulename">
     <form:option value="None" label="--Select--" />
      <c:forEach var="service" items="${modulename}">
       <optgroup label="${service.key}">
       <form:options items="${service.value}"/>        
       </optgroup>
      </c:forEach>        
    </form:select>
```

then you need to add the items in the list.